# Unable to use fingerprint sensor on asus vivobook pro

Tags: 17.10, asus, fingerprint-reader

I have an asus vivobook pro with ubuntu 17.10 installed, i spent days trying to figure out how to set up and use the fingerprint scanner. Both fingerprint-gui and fprint don't see any device available. This is the output of lsusb:
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b57a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/UEFI settings for a checkoff to perhaps enable the fingerprint sensor?

Comment: yes i've already checked but i found no settings for fingerprint devices in uefi, neither in normal mode nor in advanced

Comment: I found this post which seems to be going in the right direction. I'm also looking for a solution on this laptop. https://askubuntu.com/questions/995677/how-to-make-fingerprint-work-on-asus-vivobook-s15-s510uq/1031045#1031045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, lsusb command in some case, as for my ASUS VivoBook PRO can show no info about the touchpad / fingerprint reader.

Anyway Device ID can be acquired from commands:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i "Mouse\|Touchpad"

xinput list | grep -i "Mouse\|Touchpad"
```

Then you can check if your device has a supported driver for libprint here:

https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html

Unfortunately although touchpad  works well even , fingerprint reader integrated in the touchpad of Asus Vivobook S15 is neither recognized in ubuntu as an USB device (lsusb) nor as a libfprint device (fingerprint-gui -d).

If not present in the list  above you cannot use it with ubuntu until driver will be implemented to work with libprint.