# How to make fingerprint work on ASUS vivobook s15 S510UQ?

Tags: 16.04, asus, fingerprint-reader

Maybe someone has posted this problem, but this is a more specific explanation. I just bought a new ASUS Vivobook s15 s510uq laptop. Of course, I installed Ubuntu on it. I have tried many tutorials and also installed `fingerprint-gui` as well as `fprint`, but they don't see any device available.

Below is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Below is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
```

Not sure which one is the fingerprint device. But the case is not only "No devices found". When the screen is locked and I try to unlock it, sometimes in the bottom it shows the notification that I can login using fingerprint. Feels like the fingerprint is detected.

Maybe anyone can help? What can I do with this?

Comment: I'm sorry telling you that the driver for our fingerprint sensor is not ported for linux until this date. (source: http://home.ullrich-online.cc/fingerprint/Forum/topic.php?TopicId=615 ) thanks for reading

Comment: Just looking around, but can't find any solution. Thank you for telling me

Comment: Found any solution for this? Its even a year already :(

Comment: Couldn't find any. Even I changed my laptop already

Comment: any update? I'm having the same prob.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I also changed my laptop already. You can refer to the first comment, there is no driver for Linux.

Comment: I'm working on a driver; if you want to try the prototype it's over at https://github.com/mincrmatt12/elan-spi-fingerprint. Someone reported the libfprint fork (which should let you login with the device if you build it) works with the s510uq

Comment: Hey thank you @mincrmatt12, but now I'm not using that laptop anymore. But with the new laptop still needs the driver. I'm using Dell Latitude 7390 now, maybe you know how to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

These sensors should be working in the new 1.92 release of libfprint. Not many distributions have incorporated it yet, but you can build it from [source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint).