# How to set up the fingerprint reader on Asus Vivobook in 19.04

Tags: asus, 19.04, fingerprint-reader

I am attempting to set up the fingerprint reader on my Asus VivoBook 15 (X512DA_F512DA).  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982593/unable-to-use-fingerprint-sensor-on-asus-vivobook-pro) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995677/how-to-make-fingerprint-work-on-asus-vivobook-s15-s510uq/1031045#1031045) touch on the subject, but haven't been answered, and aren't for Dingo and aren't for my particular comp.

I've installed fingerprint GUI according to [this site](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu) and fprint according to [this Unix/Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518521/no-fingerprint-button-in-ubuntu-19-04), but they don't recognize my device.  There's no fingerprint option in the BIOS or UEFI.

Has anyone with this Asus laptop gotten their fingerprint reader to work in Dingo?